# How to merge count and sum queries in one query in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have  problem with queries in my Controller. I want to count rows and sum by column in one query.

**Relations view**

[image: a busy cat]

So far, I created two queries:

**Query to count rows**

```
$paymentsCount = Payments::where('pay_status', 'like', "%{$payStatus}%")->count();
```

**Query to sum**

```
$paymentsValue = Payments::where('pay_status', 'like', "%{$payStatus}%")->sum('brutto');
```

I have no Idea, how to make on query instead this two queries.

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query builder allows you to customize your `SELECT` clause with the [`select()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects) method.

Use it to add `COUNT()` and `SUM()` in addition of the other columns:

```php
$payments = Payments::select('*', 'COUNT(*) AS count', 'SUM(brutto) AS sum')
    ->where('pay_status', 'LIKE', "%{$payStatus}%")
    ->get();
```

Comment: Unknown column 'count(*)' in 'field